# How does React's createElement(...) work ? What are the props used for?

Tags: reactjs

I read [this](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.createelement):

```
ReactElement createElement(
  string/ReactClass type,
  [object props],
  [children ...]
)
```

> Create and return a new ReactElement of the given type. The type
>   argument can be either an html tag name string (eg. 'div', 'span',
>   etc), or a ReactClass (created via React.createClass).

This does not really explain to me what happens to `[object props]`. Why is it needed ? What is it used for ?

Could someone explain what happens to `[object props]` when calling to `createElement` ? How are they used ? Will they be used to render the element ? Can they change later ? Are they mutable or immutable ?

Reason for asking : I am trying to figure out [how to use](https://github.com/jhegedus42/scalajs-react-playaround/wiki/ReactJS-----ScalaJS-React-Interop) scalajs-react.

Comment: This link may be helpful : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/transferring-props.html

Comment: instead of createElement , you can look over `extend component`

Comment: `extend component` ? will that explain something ? isn't that just yet another syntactic sugar (complicating things)?

Comment: this is a nice explanation : https://medium.com/@rajaraodv/the-inner-workings-of-virtual-dom-666ee7ad47cf

Comment: You may checkout [this posts](https://dev.to/fromaline/deep-dive-into-react-codebase-ep3-reverse-engineer-the-most-famous-react-snippet-njj#what-raw-reactcreateelement-endraw-does-and-how-it-works) for explanation how `React.createElement` works.

Answer (score 4):

Some time ago Dan Abramov posted this on Twitter:

[image: https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/781620845185732608]

(which i think was the start of that "How React Works - implementation notes" post abhirathore2006 showed).

You can see that plunk here: http://jsbin.com/qiguyibolu/1/edit?js,output

For example, thats what's happening with the props:

```
var node = document.createElement(type);
Object.keys(props).forEach(propName => {
    if (propName !== 'children') {
        node.setAttribute(propName, props[propName]);
    }
});
```

They end up as node attributes! So i really recommend you to read https://facebook.github.io/react/contributing/implementation-notes.html to get a deeper understanding on when we call function passing props, and how we update them. Guys did a great job explaining how the things work under the hood. I'm still doing it myself actually :)

Answer (score 1):

for all those who ever wonder how react actually works ? checkout the below link which provides sneak peak into the react implementation

[How React Works - implementation notes](https://facebook.github.io/react/contributing/implementation-notes.html)